# posting an event to facebook using an application token using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been struggling with something and I seem to be missing something. I want to post events to Facebook using my Facebook appid / appsecret. The events should be owned by the application and not by any user. I try to do this as follows :

```
 var fc = new FacebookClient();
 fc.AppId = "myappid";
 fc.AppSecret = "myappsecret";

 //get a token
 dynamic result = fc.Get("oauth/access_token", new
 {
     client_id = fc.AppId,
     client_secret = fc.AppSecret,
     grant_type = "client_credentials"
 });

 //use the token to post to FB?
 fc = new FacebookClient(token);
 JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
 json.Add("name", HtmlUtils.StripHtmlTags(@event.Title));
 json.Add("description", HtmlUtils.StripHtmlTags(@event.Description));
 json.Add("start_time", @event.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
 json.Add("no_feed_story","true");

 //here i get an error
 var id = fc.post("/myappid/events",json);
```

> (OAuthException - #1) An unknown error has occurred.

What am I doing wrong? My app is not in sandbox mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

You used -

```
\POST /myappid/events
```

This is an **invalid** request. The events are posted on the **user page** or the **fan page** **via** an app.

There's nothing like "posting an event on the app"